# Save listView data like Facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, listview

I want save data like Facebook. As you seen when you have no internet it show the post that loaded last time. I know how to create custom listview but problem is that when you close the app it also destroy the data. I searched and I found something that we can save listview data in sharedpreference but I think we can only save string data there. How Face save your status,images and videos are they using sharedpreference or anyother thing. Any tutorial or something where I can learn this.

Comment: This might help you https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation on **Sqlite**. Here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html